# Compare objects and remove equal values

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-5

I want to be able to compare two objects and remove the properties which values has not been changed.

```
prevObject = {
  isActive: true,
  userName: 'Patric',
  settings: {
    isUser: true
  }
}


nextObject = {
  isActive: true,
  userName: 'Patric Surname',
  settings: {
    isUser: false
  }
}
```

The result when comparing above should be:

```
{
  userName: 'Patric Surname',
  settings: {
    isUser: false
  }
}
```

I've tried some for in loops and such, but I haven't gotten it to work recursively. Sorry, I don't have any code to show that I've tried. I trashed it since I was a bit frustrated. I'm also stuck to pure ES5 on this one. So no lodash or underscore :)

Would be really glad for some help!

Comment: What if `nextObject` omits some properties?

Answer (score 2):

You'll need a recursive approach:

In ECMAScript-5 syntax:

```js
function isObject(a) {
    return typeof a === "object" && a;
}

function diff(a, b) {
    var res = b instanceof Array ? [] : {};
    for (var prop in b) {
        if (!(prop in a) || (!isObject(a[prop]) || !isObject(b[prop])) && a[prop] !== b[prop]) {
            res[prop] = b[prop];
        } else {
            var obj = diff(a[prop], b[prop]);
            // If the recursive result is not an empty object, then use it
            for (var _ in obj) {
                res[prop] = obj;
                break; // We only need 1 iteration
            }
        }
    }
    return res; 
}

var prevObject = {isActive: true,userName: 'Patric',settings: {isUser: true }};
var nextObject = { isActive: true,userName: 'Patric Surname',settings: {isUser: false}};

console.log(diff(prevObject, nextObject));
```

This function has some limited support for arrays. Array elements are only considered the same if their content is the same and the index where they occur in the array. This means that a resulting array may have gaps ("sparse").

Answer (score 1):

```js
var prevObject = {
  isActive: true,
  userName: 'Patric',
  settings: {
    isUser: true
  }
};

var nextObject = {
  isActive: true,
  userName: 'Patric Surname',
  settings: {
    isUser: false
  }
};

var changes = Object.entries(nextObject).reduce((acc,cv)=>{
  if(JSON.stringify(nextObject[cv[0]]) != JSON.stringify(prevObject[cv[0]]))
    acc.push(cv);
  return acc;
},[]).reduce((acc,cv)=>{
  acc[cv[0]]=cv[1];
  return acc;
},{});

console.log(changes);
```

Assuming both `prevObject` and `nextObject` have the same properties.
`Object.entries` of `nextObject` returns an `Array` of `[key, value]`s.
Initialize return value of `reduce` on that `Array` to an empty `Array` - `[]`.
Fill it with properties if their `JSON.stringify` are different.
`JSON.stringify` comparison relieves us from checking type, etc.  For example: `[1,2,3]` is NOT equal `[1,2,3]`, but `JSON.stringify([1,2,3])==JSON.stringify([1,2,3])` IS.  Same for objects, etc.
We use `reduce` on the last created `Array` using `{}` as initial value, filling with properties (`cv[0]`) and their values (`cv[1]`) back into an `Object`.

Comment: no way, one really does not want to rely on `JSON.stringify` for object comparison. Even if both objects just feature valid JSON data, one already runs into problems with an identical keyset but a different order of an object's key creation. And how about values that are `Date` instances?

Comment: @FZs, added detailed explanation, per your suggestion.  Thank you!

Comment: @PeterSeliger, yes way, I do.  They do, one don't.  And `d1=new Date(); d2=new Date(d1);` `JSON.stringify(d1)==JSON.stringify(d2)` is `true`, and so is `JSON.stringify(d1=d2=new Date())==JSON.stringify(d2)`.
Expanding:
"They do" - at least for the question's example, and no methods were mentioned.
"one don't" - order of creation doesn't matter in my answer.
"Date instances" - see earlier in this comment.
No further discussion on the matter is needed if based on opinion, not supported by facts, or with similar "off" attitude (as I perceive it).